# Ajax File Uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Im trying to submit a form that has a file input via ajax. I have a few important things that need to happen.

1. The file input should be triggered by a button (done)
2. The form should be submitted when a file has been selected (done)
3. The page should NOT refresh and I should be able to check the result in the standard ajax fashion.

I have tried to do this myself, but nothing I find fits my needs.

The user needs to see a button like this, instead of the standard form input:

[image: button]

I have used the following code:

```
        <form id="uploadProfilePictureForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display: none">
            <input name="uploadProfilePicture" id="uploadProfilePicture" type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" style="display: none;"/>
        </form>
        <a id="changeProfileButtonIcon" class="btn btn-info float-right mx-0 my-0">Change (in progress)</a>


          <script>
            $("#changeProfileButtonIcon").on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#uploadProfilePicture:hidden").trigger('click');
             });
          </script>
```

This opens the input correctly, and if I have the action set to my upload page, the image is uploaded when the select dialog is closed and then I just see a white page with my success message (as expected)

Because I don't want a page refresh I have attempted to do this via jQuery:

```
$("#uploadProfilePictureForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/helpers/upload_image.php", // Url to which the request is send
                type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
                data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
                contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
                cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
                processData: false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
                success: function (data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
                {
                    var a = 1;
                }
            });
        }));
```

I placed a breakpoint on the line "preventDefault" and also on the "var a = 1" none of these get triggered and the page just refreshes.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a form if all you're doing is uploading (a) file(s). You method of having a button trigger a click on another button which triggers a click on a third thing is overly complicated.And you should not mix event attributes with event listeners.

```js
$("#realBtn").change(function(){
  var formData = new FormData();
  for(var i=this.files.length; i--;)
    formData.append('uploadProfilePicture[]', this.files[i], this.files[i].name);
  $.ajax({
      url: "/helpers/upload_image.php",
      type: "POST", 
      data: formData,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (data){
          console.log("upload complete");
      }
  });
});

// Trigger the real file upload button
$("#fakeBtn").click(()=>$("#realBtn").click());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="realBtn" type="file" style="display: none;" />
<input id="fakeBtn" type="button" value='click to upload stuff'/>
```

That said, you should take advantage of one of the many jQuery plugins that does all the dirty work for you, like [this one](https://github.com/Pamblam/fileUpload), that I wrote.

There are many reason you should use this instead...

- it handles the upload part,
- it lets you show the image preview while it's uploading,
- it lets you see upload progress,
- it supports drag and drop,
- it's capable of only allowing a certain type of file (like images)
- etc etc.

```js
$("#fileBtn").fileUpload({
  url: "/path/to/upload.php",
  accept: "image/gif, image/png, image/jpeg, .png, .gif, .jpg",
  change: function(){
    $("#preview").html("Loading...");
    $("#fileBtn").fileUpload("getDataURI", function(dataURI){
      $("#preview").html("<b>Your image: </b><br><img src='"+dataURI+"' />");
    }); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Pamblam/fileUpload/master/fileUpload.js"></script>

<div id=preview></div>
<button id=fileBtn>click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for an indepth answer, ill check it out in a few minutes and accept if its correct for me.